# Only return Jekyll posts that match specific year

Tags: jekyll, liquid

How do I loop through a Jekyll site's posts but only take action on posts where the year is equal to a specific value?

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% if post.date.year == 2012 %}
      <p>{{ post.date }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

The above does not work. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To extract the year of a date, you have to use the `date` filter with `"%Y"` (the full syntax is listed [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/liquid/4.0.0/Liquid/StandardFilters#date-instance_method)). i.e.:

```
{% for post in site.posts %}
  {% capture year %}{{post.date | date: "%Y"}}{% endcapture %}
  {% if year == "2012" %}
      <p>{{ post.date }}</p>
      <p>{{ post.title }}</p>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That really works for you? I never managed to make such `if` condition to work. Neither yours work with Jekyll 0.11.2 and Liquid 2.3.0.

Comment: @manatwork Oops, it certainly _appeared_ to work when I tested it, but I missed the fact that it didn't.... Fixed now.

Comment: So, how would you do this, but check for the existence of any post during that year? For example, if there are posts in 2008, print an h4.